# 'Can be fined or are fined ' What's the difference between them?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> A) People who drop litter can be fined in some countries.
>   B) People who drop litter are fined in some countries.

In the sentence A the subject speaks about the possibility of the action-fining so that the auxiliary- can is used and it implies that the very subject is not sure about the fact.

In the sentence B) the subject is very sure about the fact of the fining and the simple present tense is used.

Please make sure if I am in the right way of understanding those sentences or not.

Answer (score 1):

True, the first sentence talks about the *possibilities* of the punishment whereas in the second sentence, it gives a *statement* that they **will be fined** if they litter.

So, in those sentences, *can be...* shows hypothetical condition and *are fined...* is definite.

Comment: I got. In the same context do you think If the aux- can  can be replaced with may, might and could?

Comment: Yes! But the meaning may change. Say, people who litter might get fined talks about uncertainty. The speaker is *not sure*

Comment: Thank you. And again, More than talking about the possibilities the sentence with can be fined implies the speaker feels the agent has the permission for imposing the fine, doesn't it? (I mean the agent has the right to do that.)